# How to call (and sleep) on gen_tcp:accept and still process system messages at the same time?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I'm still kind of new to the erlang/otp world, so I guess this is a pretty basic question. Nevertheless I'd like to know what's the correct way of doing the following.

Currently, I have an application with a top supervisor. The latter will supervise workers that call gen_tcp:accept (sleeping on it) and then spawn a process for each accepted connection. Note: To this question, it is irrelevant where the listen() is done.

My question is about the correct way of making these workers (the ones that sleep on gen_tcp:accept) respect the otp design principles, in such a way that they can handle system messages (to handle shutdown, trace, etc), according to what I've read here: http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/spec_proc.html

So,

- Is it possible to use one of the available behaviors like gen_fsm or gen_server for this? My guess would be no, because of the blocking call to gen_tcp:accept/1. Is it still possible to do it by specifying an accept timeout? If so, where should I put the accept() call?
- Or should I code it from scratch (i.e: not using an existant behavior) like the examples in the above link? In this case, I thought about a main loop that calls gen_tcp:accept/2 instead of gen_tcp:accept/1 (i.e: specifying a timeout), and immediately afterwards code a receive block, so I can process the system messages. Is this correct/acceptable?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually found the answer in another question: [Non-blocking TCP server using OTP principles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170613/non-blocking-tcp-server-using-otp-principles/6173232#6173232) and here http://20bits.com/article/erlang-a-generalized-tcp-server

**EDIT**: The specific answer that was helpful to me was: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6513913/727142

Comment: Neither answer solves the question described.  Both use a `gen_server` that receives system messages, but both put `accept` "work" outside the worker process.  The trapexit article uses `prim_inet:accept`, which is an internal, undocumented API (subject to change without notice at any point). The 20bits article spawns a handrolled accept via `proc_lib:spawn` (adding a wrapper, but not *solving* the issue). Both avoid `gen_tcp:accept`'s blocking nature, but release control of `accept` and require cleanup (managing the spawned process and having to process messages, respectively).

Comment: It does answer my question by explaining how to write a special process that uses accept with a timeout and then processes system messages, and without using undocumented features. I was not asking how to write a non blocking accept, and I did not spawn another process to do the accept. The code posted in the answer that describes the special process was one of the possibilities I was asking about in my question

Comment: I don't see `accept` being used with a timeout in either the 20bits or trapexit article. Could you update your answer to show the link you found that uses the timeout? I would be very interested to see another approach, especially a spec_proc compliant version!

Comment: @mlb: done, I've added the link to the specific answer in that question

Answer (score 1):

As Erlang is event driven, it is awkward to deal with code that blocks as accept/{1,2} does.

Personally, I would have a supervisor which has a `gen_server` for the listener, and another supervisor for the accept workers.
Handroll an accept worker to timeout (`gen_tcp:accept/2`), effectively polling,  (the awkward part) rather than receiving an message for status.

This way, if a worker dies, it gets restarted by the supervisor above it.
If the listener dies, it restarts, but not before restarting the worker tree and supervisor that depended on that listener.
Of course, if the top supervisor dies, it gets restarted.
However, if you `supervisor:terminate_child/2` on the tree, then you can effectively disable the listener and all acceptors for that socket. Later, `supervisor:restart_child/2` can restart the whole listener+acceptor worker pool.

If you want an app to manage this for you, [cowboy](https://github.com/extend/cowboy) implements the above. Although http oriented, it easily supports a custom handler for whatever protocol to be used instead.

Comment: Thanks for the resource. Shouldn't ranch_acceptor (from cowboy source) handle system messages in its main loop, in order to respect the OTP principles and to be able to be supervised?

Comment: @marcelog ranch_acceptor is supervised, see ranch_acceptors_sup. Via the modules and supervisor, the system messages for the acceptor processes are handled.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it as a gen_server similar to this one: https://github.com/alinpopa/qerl/blob/master/src/qerl_conn_listener.erl.

As you can see, this process is doing tcp accept and processing other messages (e.g. stop(Pid) -> gen_server:cast(Pid,{close}).)

HTH,
Alin